# Bracket specification for wall-mounted desk

Tags: desk, brackets, shelf

I've ordered a new desktop which will be made of solid oak. Its dimensions are 2300mm (L) x 820mm (W) (approx. 90.5" x 32"). I doubt it's relevant except for estimating its weight but it's 27mm (1") thick).

The long edge of the desk and one of the short edges will be against masonry walls (i.e. it'll be in a corner). For clarity, here's a diagram:
[image: Diagram showing desktop with dimensions]

Ideally I want to mount it to the wall using brackets rather than legs. I'm thinking of using two (at 767mm and 1533mm) or three (at 575mm, 1150mm and 1725mm) long brackets from the back wall. I've been looking at the brackets [here](https://www.locksonline.com/Hebgo-Fixed-Shelf-Bracket-150kg-Load-Capacity-936.html).

My question is what length of bracket would I need (the ones I've linked to go up to 680mm in length) and would 3 be overkill (they're rated for 150Kg per pair)? The desk will hold three or four large computer monitors and I want to know I can lean on it without worrying!

Comment: See my answer to this question.   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/114905/what-is-the-ideal-method-of-supporting-a-27-deep-floating-desk-across-10-feet-o/114952#114952 **Great brackets**.   I do not know what kind of masonry wall you have so i can answer  about anchoring.

Comment: That looks great! Looks as if you were affixing to a stud wall whereas I've got an old brick wall which I'd like to think will be at least as sturdy!

Comment: Would love to know why somebody just downvoted this over 18 months after the last activity in relation to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those brackets are only going to be effective if you can secure them into the masonry wall in a sturdy enough way that it can resist the pullout torque exerted by the bracket.

If it was me I would not use any brackets and instead mount full length skirting boards along the walls that the desktop can sit on. Then I would definitely use a leg or end support at the open desk corner away from the wall.

Also consider that the oak top at only 27mm thick over the 2300mm length will sag or bow down with weight placed on it. You should be planning for some additional edgewise skirting boards set back some from the front and left side of the desk top that go underneath to stiffen up the top. The boards along the walls that I suggested will take care of those edges.

Comment: I take your points. I was planning to use some fairly heavy-duty wall fixings for the brackets, and I think three brackets would probably mitigate the potential for sagging if they were spaced out evenly. I did consider skirting boards, as you suggested, and may yet use those as well for added support but I don't know how much load they'd actually take away from the brackets. A leg at the totally unsupported corner is a possibility but I'd prefer to avoid it if I can.