# Estimated strength of U-profile shelf standards?

Tags: walls, wood, metal, table, shelf

I would like to make a table, which is only supported by 4 of these U-profiles. Two on each end will be screwed in a brick wall.

The shop doesn't have any specs on the U-profiles.

## Question

Assuming I can align the U-profiles exactly, so each only have to carry 1/4th of the tables weight. How many kg can I expect each U-profile can carry?

[image]
[image]

Comment: In 99% of cases the mounting or the platform will fail before the support hardware will. That's probably why there are no such specs provided. It also depends on load distribution and vector, among other things. I suggest you revise to ask about your overall design rather than this very specific (and not particularly important) data point.

Comment: Also important is the stiffness and strength of your table top. If it's very rigid most of the shear force will be applied at the connection to the upright, whereas if it's flexible a lot of force will be applied to the ends of the supports, increasing torque on the connecting tabs. Again, the overall design is important.

Comment: Unless you're mounting a very deep table and are planning on using it as a work surface, including dropping and pounding, they'll likely hold far more than you'll ever put on them. I had an 8' tall by 6' wide series of shelves supported by 6 of these types of stanchions (ours were single slot, not double). They held increasing piles of _stuff_ (mostly paper/books which are quite heavy) for 25+ years before we removed them earlier this year. There was no sign of sag or damage, and there was never any concern that the whole thing was going to tumble down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While they may work for a table that is shallow, not cantilevered off of the wall very far, it really is not the appropriate hardware for the job. Assuming you fasten the shelving standards to the brick wall with the appropriate fasteners, i feel the week link in this plan is the little tabs on the back of the bracket that hold the bracket to the standard.

I would invest in [these brackets](https://businessfurnitureshop.com/workstation-brackets.html).

I have used them to make desks, they are great and come in a variety of size's to accommodate shallow or deep desk/workbench's.

[Here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/114905/what-is-the-ideal-method-of-supporting-a-27-deep-floating-desk-across-10-feet-o/114952#114952) is a link to a desk question that I answered that shows the brackets in use.